# How can I Merge only the latest n commits from a branch, because the earlier commits in that branch are undesired?

Tags: git, merge, branch

A very prolific -- but still green with git and version control in general -- programmer joined the project and pushed a branch (many, actually) with about 30 commits.

The first 10 or so commits are changes we do not want in the master branch...ever. They create dummy components and files, commit code that doesn't compile, and even have commit messages like "Test." and "Fixed.".

The next 10 or so commits in the branch attempt to revert the changes made in the first 10 commits. The commit messages become more descriptive, but these commits really just **attempt to** delete files, remove comments, etc. that were added in the first ten commits. Without going through every commit by hand, I don't trust that this process was perfect and that everything created in the first 10 was perfectly removed in the middle 10.

The final 10 commits have actual useful changes in them. The new programmer did not learn about proper branching, which would have made my day easier, until after these final 10 commits were added to the otherwise useless branch and pushed to remote.

So, now I am tasked with merging into master (or some intermediate branch, then master) only the last 10 or so commits of each branch. There are five or so other feature branches (told you, prolific) created by this programmer with similar properties. He was merging the branch with the useless "test" commits into each new branch he created, so the first 20 or so commits of all these branches are absolute junk. He will continue to commit more to each of these branches going forward, now that he is mostly on board with our team's best practices.

**What is the best practice for merging the useful commits and discarding forever the useless ones?**

I have looked at `git cherry pick merge`, but can't get over the mysterious comment that this "breaks git's merge functionality". So, will I end up with a master branch that can't be merged into properly or is otherwise "broken"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git rebase` to just apply the commits that you want onto master. Or, you can use an interactive rebase `git rebase -i` on the source branch to remove the commits you do not need and merge to master as you normally would.

Comment: So, should I do something like this to remove the unwanted commits in place: `git checkout messybranch`, `git rebase --interactive --onto messybranch messybranch`? ...and then edit out the commits I don't want? Can I combine --onto and --interactive like that? More importantly, how do I undo the results if I completely trash the branch? I see the --abort option, but that sounds like it only aborts after a conflict.

Comment: I would use `git checkout messybranch` -> `git rebase -i HEAD~<number_of_commits_you_want_to_adjust>`. This will bring up an editor with a list of commits you can adjust. Just delete the lines with the commits you dont want to keep and save/close editor. `git` will then apply the patches that you selected. Then do a `git branch newcleanbranch` to create a branch with the new series of commits you selected. Note that `git rebase` always creates new commits and does not touch existing commits. So, if something goes wrong, you can just abort and go back to the original `messybranch`